# Support for Opentelemetry instrumentation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, open-telemetry

Is there any support for Opentelemetry instrumentation in Delphi ? Or the only way is to write COM interface for the opentelemetry.net sdk ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use OpenTelemetry .Net SDK to create some Microsoft COM objects.
Or you can lookup if any receiver of [OTel Collector contrib](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib) can help.
For example if it is log or metrics data, you can use file.